# Can't Receive Emails from HTML Contact Form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I have been trying to make this contact form work but couldn't receive emails. Everything looks fine to me. I am using a html template and trying to customize it with my limited coding knowledge. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
                        <!-- Notifications -->
                        <p class="success cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Mesajınız Gönderilmiştir.</strong></p>
                        <p class="failed cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><strong> Bir hata Oluştu! Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.</strong></p>

                        <div class="form-group w-50">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cfName" placeholder="İsim" required=""> 
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="cfEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cfSubject" placeholder="Başlık" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea id="cfMessage" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesajınız..." required=""></textarea>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group m-b-0">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-shadow btn-green" style="border-radius: 4px; font-size: 15px; box-shadow: rgb(72, 125, 101) 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 3px solid rgb(219, 141, 23); background-color: rgb(219, 141, 23);">Gönder</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and this is my php code:

```html
<?php
// Variables
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);

// Email address validation - works with php 5.2+
function is_email_valid($email) {
 return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}


if( isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message) && isset($subject) && is_email_valid($email) ) {

 // Avoid Email Injection and Mail Form Script Hijacking
 $pattern = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
 if( preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $message) || preg_match($pattern, $subject) ) {
  exit;
 }

 // Email will be send
 $to = "arda@toptal.com";  // Change with your email address
 

 // HTML Elements for Email Body
 $body = <<<EOD
 <strong>Name:</strong> $name <br>
 <strong>Email:</strong> <a href="mailto:$email?subject=feedback" "email me">$email</a> <br> <br>
 <strong>Message:</strong> $message <br>
EOD;
//Must end on first column
 
 $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
 $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 // PHP email sender
 mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
}


?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost? If so, do you use xamp or something?

Comment: give the text fields names rather than ids - the POST array uses the elements name - not id.

Comment: Have you done a var_dump on your variables you are passing to mail to make sure they are being set? Your input fields are not using the **name** attribute so these are probably not being set properly.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your PHP script will help immensely.

Comment: I am testing it live on my hosting service.

Answer (score 0):

try the form like this, with the name attribute set to that expected in the POST array

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
    <!-- Notifications -->
    <p class="success cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Mesajınız Gönderilmiştir.</strong></p>
    <p class="failed cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><strong> Bir hata Oluştu! Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.</strong></p>

    <div class="form-group w-50">
        <input name='name' type="text" class="form-control" id="cfName" placeholder="İsim" required=""> 
        <input name='email' type="email" class="form-control" id="cfEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name='subject' type="text" class="form-control" id="cfSubject" placeholder="Başlık" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name='message' id="cfMessage" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesajınız..." required=""></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group m-b-0">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-shadow btn-green" style="border-radius: 4px; font-size: 15px; box-shadow: rgb(72, 125, 101) 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 3px solid rgb(219, 141, 23); background-color: rgb(219, 141, 23);">Gönder</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used name tags like you suggested but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

you missed a name for each field

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
<!-- Notifications -->
<p class="success cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Mesajınız Gönderilmiştir.</strong></p>
<p class="failed cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><strong> Bir hata Oluştu! Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.</strong></p>
<div class="form-group w-50">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="cfName" placeholder="İsim" required=""> 
<input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email"  id="cfEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="subject"  id="cfSubject" placeholder="Başlık" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea id="cfMessage"  name="message"  rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Mesajınız..." required=""></textarea>
</div> 
<div class="form-group m-b-0">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-shadow btn-green" style="border-radius: 4px; font-size: 15px; box-shadow: rgb(72, 125, 101) 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 3px solid rgb(219, 141, 23); background-color: rgb(219, 141, 23);">Gönder</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used name tags like you suggested but still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing input type field name that why you cannot pass data to next page "contact.php"

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
<!-- Notifications -->
<p class="success cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <strong>Mesajınız Gönderilmiştir.</strong></p>
<p class="failed cf text-center"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><strong> Bir hata Oluştu! Lütfen Tekrar Deneyiniz.</strong></p>

<div class="form-group w-50">
    <label>Username*</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="cfName" placeholder="Username" required=""> 
</div>
<div class="form-group w-50">
    <label>Email*</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="cfEmail" placeholder="E-Mail" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Subject*</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="cfSubject" placeholder="Subject" required="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Message*</label>
    <textarea id="cfMessage" name="message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message..." required=""></textarea>
</div> 
<div class="form-group m-b-0">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-shadow btn-green" style="border-radius: 4px; font-size: 15px; box-shadow: rgb(72, 125, 101) 0px 0px 0px 0px; border: 3px solid rgb(219, 141, 23); background-color: rgb(219, 141, 23);">Gönder</button>
</div>
</form>
```